# cut off density plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use

```
frame <- read.table(paste('data', fname, sep="/"), sep=",", header=TRUE)
colnames(frame) <- c("pos", "word.length")
plot <- ggplot(frame, aes(x=pos, y=word.length)) + xlim(0,20) + ylim(0,20) + geom_density2d() + stat_density2d(aes(color=..level..))
png(paste("graphs/", fname, ".png", sep=""), width=600, height=600)
print(plot)
dev.off()
```

to create plots, but they get cut off. How do I fix this?

http://ompldr.org/vZTN0eQ

The data I used to create this plot: http://sprunge.us/gKiL

Comment: If I make up some data that ranges from 0 to 20 my plot looks great.  Maybe you can supply some of your data that replicates the problem?  If you omit the `xlim` and `ylim` options ggplot will pick them for you based on the limits of your data.  I suspect that is where your problem lies.

Comment: You are correct, but I've got different sets of data, some in range 3 to 10, other the full 0 to 20 range, I want them comparable. Apparently the `lim`s aren't passed correctly.

Comment: The limits are passed exactly as you've passed them, 0:20.  so the data that range from 3:10 look "cut off" because they don't extend to the edges of the plot.  Again, if you supply some of your data you can get a better answer.  I would suggest putting the data into one data.frame and plotting with `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` and fixing your scales.  that way all the plots are together with one scale.

Comment: Thanks for adding some data, and maybe I still don't understand the question, but I maintain that `ggplot` is doing exactly what you've asked it to do.  Your data has a y range of `3:16` and an x range of `2:9`, which is what is plotted.  However, you have also told `ggplot` that you want the limits of the graph to extend from 0 to 20, which is what your linked plot show.

Comment: So I've confused `lim`s with ranges. Can I tell `ggplot` I'd like it assume different ranges, according to the limits?

Comment: You can, but you don't have to.  By default `ggplot` will determine appropriate ranges given the data you supply.

Comment: They look well on their own, but in that case, it's a matter of aesthetics. How do I change the ranges on which `density_2d` will operate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the ggplot2 book, you use `scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1,20))` instead of `xlim(1,20)` for that.